# return the index of the first element of the array A whose value is greater or equal to m

Tags: java, arrays, oop, if-statement, for-loop

```
public class Accumulator {
    private int[] A;
    public Accumulator(int[] X) {
        A= new int[X.length];
        for (int i=0; i<X.length; i++){
            A[i] = X[i];
        }


        }
    public int getOverM(int m){
            for(int j=0; j<A.length;j++){
                if(m < A[j])
                {

                }

            }



        }
    public static void main(String args[]){ // you can use the main method to test your code

        int[] A = {2,4,3,5,8};

        int r=new Accumulator(A).getOverM(3); //change argument to test different cases
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```

}

Hi I have been working on this for so long i know it seems easy but i just cant get my head around it....I can only change the code inside the method getOverM(), I cannot edit other methods.
I thought of using an if statement,but I just do not know how to write a code that shows the next biggest index number compared to the m.

Question:Consider the following Accumulator class with missing code for the method 
'getOverM(int m)'. 
getOverM should return the index of the first element of the array A whose 
value is greater or equal to m.

If no element in A has index greater or equal to m then the method 
should return -1. 
For example if A is the array {2,4,3,5,8} then
getOverM(3) will return 1
getOverM(2) will return 0
getOverM(7) will return 4
getOverM(20) will return -1

(Hint: the length of an array A is given by A.length)

Insert the code for the body of the method getOverM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you have been looking for

```
public int getOverM(int m){
        for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
              if(m <= A[j]){            //if the current element is greater than or equal to m then return the index .
                 return j;        
              }
        } 
        return -1; // return -1 if the loop ends by not finding any element which is greater than or equal to m
    }
```

Comment: omg u are a life saver man. I knew it was not a complicated code...thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can return this index like this.

```
public int getOverM(int m){
    for(int j=0; j<A.length;j++){
          if(m <= A[j]){
            flag=0;  
            break;
          }
          else flag=1;
    } 
    if(!flag)
      return j;
    else return -1;
}
```

Comment: It will return the first greater element than m

Comment: Can you throw some more light

Comment: Read the question again

Comment: "getOverM should return the index of the first element of the array A whose value is greater or equal to m."

Comment: your solution fails if no element is greater or equal to m

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getOverM(int m){
            int index = -1;
            for(int j=0; j<A.length;j++){
                if(m <= A[j])
                {
                   index = j;
                   break;
                }
            }
            return index;
}
```

Comment: That will return last index, not first index.

Comment: Wait what?Please be more specific in order for me to improve myself.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was wrong. That won't compile, because `j` is not in scope in the `return j`. I had read that as `return index`, and since you don't break on setting the value, the loop continues and keeps replacing the value, such that the return value is the *last* index matched, not the first.

Comment: My bad index is the variable i want to return.

Answer (score 0):

First, `getOverM()` should return "index greater *or equal to* m", so you need `<=`.

Otherwise, all you are missing are the return statements:

```
public int getOverM(int m) {
    for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
        if (m <= A[j])
            return j;
    return -1;
}
```